# Convert text string to formula in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I have a spreadsheet that generates formulae as text ex.

```
=CONCATENATE("+B",ROW(),"*",ROUND(G5,2))
```

output:

```
 +B5*1464.41
```

I have a column of this type of text that I need to convert into individual formulae. Right now, I copy the text to a new column, and then push the '=' button for each row.
Is there a way to automate this? or do it in bulk?

Comment: You could write a short user-defined function as suggested at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/73743-convert-text-formula.html.  Unfortunately LibreOffice Basic doesn't include the `Evaluate()` function, so you'd have to figure out how to call a function in another language (such as JavaScript or Python).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, the solution is rather obvious.

Highlight the text in question.
Use Find to replace the leading '+' with a '='

The cells will recalculate as a formula instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression with "paste special".
All cells have a leading - generally invisible - character defining the cell type.

So:

1. Select all the cells with the textual formula and press CTRL+H.
2. in the FIND box type `^.`. (You may have to type the `^` symbol twice to make it appear - then backspace to delete one of them and type the period `.`)
3. In the REPLACE box type `&`. Make sure Regular Expressions box is checked
4. Select FIND ALL which should highlight all your selected cells
5. Select REPLACE ALL

Comment: In step 3, does the & indicate a formula? The regex seems to indicate that you are replacing the first character with an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

whenever i have a considerable number of text lines that i need to convert to executable code, i copy/paste the text lines from the spreadsheet into an ordinary, blank libreoffice writer document and then copy/paste them from the document into a libreoffice calc spreadsheet.

the pasting into the writer document must be **paste special/unformatted**.  then the pasting from the writer document into a spreadsheet must be ordinary paste - not unformatted.

i've had 20,000 lines of code that had been generated as text execute immediately using this method.

edit - i really like your method, frog.  what i've been doing is limited to columns of code, while your method works equally well on rows of code.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the author's question.